# sessionStorage not set when function is run before redirect (React Router Dom v6)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session-storage

I have two nearly identical functions:

This one works

```
    function addToCart(id) {
      setProductsCartNew((prevProductsCart) => [...prevProductsCart, id]);
      alert("Product added to cart");
    }
```

This one does not

```
    function handleCheckout(id) {
      setProductsCartNew((prevProductsCart) => [...prevProductsCart, id]);
      navigate("/checkout");
    }
```

useEffect:

```
    useEffect(() => {
      sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(productsCartNew));
    }, [productsCartNew]);
```

Why is that so? I do get redirected, so that part of the function works.

I have checked the value of "productsCartNew", and it does in fact get updated, it's just that it doesn't get set in the sessionStorage that is the problem.

Comment: My advice would be to store in session after `setProductsCartNew` (is it a useState hook? ) 
`setProductsCartNew((prevState) => { const newState = [...prevState, id]; sessionStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(newState)); return newState;  });`

Comment: Exact same result. When I'm redirected to the checkout page, the session is not set.

Comment: Weird, session should be kept within the browser tab, reload would clear it though... can you try with localStorage instead? Just for test.

Comment: Coud you create a reproducible code I could try? Code sandbox or similar?

Comment: The `useEffect` hook will trigger on the next render after you set the state. However, you are using `navigate` on the first render so there is no other render. render 1: `setState` + `navigate`, render 2: `useEffect` + `sessionStorage`. You never get to render 2.

Comment: that would be true, but OP says it also doesnt work on first render setState + session storage as I suggested.

Comment: I think I worded that poorly. The session is "set", it just doesn't get the new value inserted if the redirect goes through. I have no idea on how to set up CodeSandbox or similar, sorry :(

Comment: The function `addToCart` does not perform a redirect, so that's fine and it shoud work. `handleCheckout` on the other hand might prevent the last update because it redirects before saving to `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design the setState is asynchronous so the value will be actually updated some time in the future.
Since you're navigating to a different page (/checkout) I assume you do not need to actually change state in the starting component as you need to pass it to the destination page.

The correct way of handling your logic is as follows:

Remove the useEffect and move the logic inside the `handleCheckout` func:

```
function handleCheckout(id) {
  const cartArray = [...productsCartNew, id]; // productsCartNew is the state array
  sessionStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cartArray));
  navigate("/checkout");
}
```

In this way you're able to pass every product added to cart plus the id passed to the handle function, set the sessionStorage correctly and then navigate to the checkout page where the information from the sessionStorage is retrieved.